# Como ocultar arquivos programaticamente

Tags: linux, arquivo, raspberry-pi

Um arquivo oculto em ambiente linux tem como característica possuir um ponto (<kbd>.</kbd>) antes de seu nome, de forma que, por exemplo: `.arquivo.c` é oculto e `arquivo.c` não é. Sabendo disso, a minha questão é, como ocultar uma série de arquivos de forma programática? E se eu puder ir além, como ocultar arquivos somente de uma determinada extensão?

Tenho ciência de duas possibilidades até então:

- Os renomeando, um a um.
- Utilizando um arquivo `.hidden`¹.

Entretanto a primeira opção me parece inviável e a segunda, apesar de ser exatamente o que eu estou procurando, não foi efetiva no ambiente em que trabalho, de um raspberry. **Há outra opção?**

---

> ¹Um .hidden é utilizado para determinar o que será
>   ocultado em um determinado diretório.

Comment: Não foi efetiva em que sentido?

Comment: Não funcionou. Eu criei um arquivo .hidden, listei alguns arquivos para ocultar e nada aconteceu.

Comment: Por que a primeira opção seria inviável?

Comment: @ngueno porque pressuponho existir algum método capaz de fazer o que procuro de maneira mais eficiente. O hidden se me servisse já resolveria bastante.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva Desculpe, poderia editar sua pergunta colocando também o código ou o método que fez para tentar ocultar?

Comment: o método usando o arquivo .hidden só funciona com o gerenciador de arquivos Nautilus do ambiente Gnome, que eu saiba...no terminal não funciona

Comment: @zentrunix cheguei a conclusão semelhante. Mantive a pergunta em aberto na esperança de haver uma solução que eu desconheça.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se entendi o sentido de 'programática' acho iria querer ler sobre [regex](https://regexr.com/). Então, usando o pipe direto no terminal é possível fazer o que procura:

```
ls -1 | grep "\.<extensão>$" | xargs -i mv {} .{}
```

Claro, a solução acima é bem simples e terá que ser executada de diretório em diretório.